# Conditional Formatting For a Checklist Using AND function with DATE and Checkboxes

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to make a list with dates and checkboxes. How can I use conditional formatting to highlight only cells in column A if another column, row 1 is today's date and the checkboxes underneath in the corresponding rows are true? Also, its ok if it highlights the entire row.

Using the custom formula in conditional formatting

```
=AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4))=TODAY(), B2=TRUE)
```

with the range A2:A6, I didn't get any results.

[image]

*EDIT: I've figured it out. It's =AND(OFFSET($A1, 0, MATCH(TODAY(), $1:$1, 0) - 1) = TRUE)

MATCH looks for the column number with today's date. OFFSET looks for the checkboxes that are true in that column. AND ensures both are true so that the formula only affects checkboxes for today's date.

Answer (score 0):

```
=filter($B2:$H2,$B$1:$H$1=today())
```

or

```
=xlookup(today(),$B$1:$H$1,$B2:$H2)
```

applied to range `A2:A5`

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to highlight the corresponding cells in column A. It would be dynamic so the highlight only applies to each new day.

Comment: @JonN answer updated!